# Setting Wallpaer in android

Tags: java, android

I want to build a simple wallpaper app but just can't set the wallpaper. I have tried many methods but just can't understand how to implement wallpapermanager.

```
final LinearLayout L1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l1);
final ImageView I1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ImageView I2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
ImageView I3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
ImageView I4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
ImageView I5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
ImageView I6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
ImageView I7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
ImageView I8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
ImageView I9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
ImageView I10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
ImageView I11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
ImageView I12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
ImageView I13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView13);
ImageView I14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView14);
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
final WallpaperManager my = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

I1.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {
                              {
                                      /*abc = 1;
                                      if(abc==1) {
                                          L1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                          abc = 0;
                                      }*/

                              }
                          }
                      }
);

I2.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {
                              I1.setBackground(getDrawable(p));
                          }
                      }
);

I3.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {
                              I1.setBackground(getDrawable(r));
                          }
                      }
);

I4.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {
                              I1.setBackground(getDrawable(s));
                          }
                      }
);

I5.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {
                              I1.setBackground(getDrawable(t));
                          }
                      }
);

I6.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {
                              I1.setBackground(getDrawable(u));
                          }
                      }
);

I7.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {
                              I1.setBackground(getDrawable(t));
                          }
                      }
);

I8.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {
                              I1.setBackground(getDrawable(s));
                          }
                      }
);

I9.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {
                              I1.setBackground(getDrawable(w));
                          }
                      }
);

I10.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                               I1.setBackground(getDrawable(x));
                           }
                       }
);

I11.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                               I1.setBackground(getDrawable(y));
                           }
                       }
);

I12.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                               I1.setBackground(getDrawable(z));
                           }
                       }
);

I13.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                               I1.setBackground(getDrawable(zz));
                           }
                       }
);

I14.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                               I1.setBackground(getDrawable(xx));
                           }
                       }
);

b1.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {
                              my.setResource(R.drawable.);
                          }
                      }
);
```

Comment: are you trying to build app for live wallpaper?

Comment: I'm really confused what you want, but this code won't compile. Please make a [mcve] with an [edit] to your question. I think only showing one ImageView is necessary to ask your question, not 14.

Comment: I want to press the button and the wallpaper in the ImageView1 to be applied to the homescreen, but i don't understand how to use wallpaper manager.

Comment: @Aditya no, still wallpaper app.